# Automatically closing of Current working window is quitting the driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

I want to perform the below steps

1. Launch application
2. Click on link on the application - new window opens
   3.switch to new window and do required actions - window closed after doing required actions
3. Switch to parent window and do the remaining actions

But at point no 3 the driver is quitting it's instance and further steps are failing since driver instance is closed

Could someone please suggest me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have clicked on a **WebElement** on **Page1** , you would be redirected to **Page2** , Now use this **code** :

```
        //Page1 some operations

        //click on a web element which redirects/opens a new tab/window

        ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
        driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));

        //perform some operations on second tab/window

        driver.close(); // closing the Page2 windows or tab/windows

        driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(0));

        //Now your webdriver has foucs on Page1 

       // do remaining operations on Page1
```

Note that you should use only `driver.close()` when you are at second page , do not use **driver.quit()**  as it would close the whole instance.